# Punctuation: comma in this sentence?

Tags: punctuation, clauses

I am wondering whether this sentence is correct:

> The scenes consist of about 400 images showing a non-moving ball at various locations while the rest are sequences of a moving ball.

...or if there has to be comma:

> The scenes consist of about 400 **images, showing** a non-moving ball at various locations while the rest are sequences of a moving ball.

Since *The scenes consist of about 400 images* is the main clause, I would consider that a comma is needed there...but I am not sure.

**EDIT:** Meanwhile a colleague of mine suggested the following:

> The scenes consist of about 400 **images, showing** a non-moving ball at various **locations, while** the rest are sequences of a moving ball.

Comment: I won't put a comma because you are *not* breaking the sentence. It's quite similar to *"I saw him (no comma) eating an apple along with a banana"*

Answer (score 3):

Technically you don't need a comma, though it is awfully close to being a run-on sentence without one. If you did put one in, I would actually put it before ***while*** as the clause following is independent, which means it's okay to separate the clauses with a comma. It's also likely where you would pause if you were saying the sentence aloud:

> The scenes consist of about 400 images showing a non-moving ball at various locations, while the rest are sequences of a moving ball.